# Pause an Android activity when a Dialog is shown

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, onpause

I have a question about activity and dialog interaction. In my Android application I have a page that allow the user to scan a QRCode, and when a valid QRCode is scanned the application will open a Dialog. The problem is that I want to disable the automate scanning in the background activity when the Dialog is shown. **Is there any way to disable the activity in background when the Dialog is in foreground?** (even if the dialogue in question is on the same activity?).

I tried to call "onPause()" method but it doesn't works..

Thank you for your help!

If necessary I edit this post with part of the code :)

Comment: You don't call `onPause()`, the platform does. You need to stop the _scanning process_, but not the activity itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {

    private boolean mustScan = true;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        if (mustScan) {
            // Just scan
            // Note: If you use a Thread with a while loop, use this:
            // while (true) {if (mustScan) {} }
        }
    }

    // This is the method you use to show the Dialog
    private void showResults (SomeResults here) {
        // Show the dialog
        // ...
        mustScan = false;
        // Also, in the OnClickListener of the buttons add "mustScan = true;"
    }
```